# How to convert the uploaded file in Box.com?

Tags: salesforce, box-api, apex, force.com

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45823/how-to-download-uploaded-file-in-box-com/46515#46515

In the above link the code will give an url (in the response) to download the file. But i want the file to be downloaded in HTML format. As per the box.com website i.e., https://developers.box.com/view/  they have given that we can convert the files to HTML. How can i do this using salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

@Srilakshmi B S

If you want to download the file as HTML, you'll have to take the file and send it to the Box View service/API for conversion. The Box content API doesn't by itself allow you to convert documents for preview and download into HTML. That means that you'll need two separate tokens if using both API endpoint. If you are in fact planning to use both, there's some documentation here on how:

https://developers.box.com/using-the-view-api-with-the-content-api/

Comment: I am able to get the file as HTML and also SVG content of the file and one png file (1st page of the file). But In place of SVG I want . png or .jpg format. Any way to achieve this?